# what means this?

Tags: power-supply

what means evga psu GS and G ?

[http://www.amazon.com/EVGA-SuperNOVA-80PLUS-Certified-220-G2-0850-XR/dp/B00IKDETOC/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1434314521&sr=8-2&keywords=evga+psu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IKDETOC)

Comment: It means nothing it's just a product line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSU - power supply unit (device that powers your computer)

EVGA - manufacturer of these devices

G and GS - product lines, GS are more expensive silent ones. G are cheaper, standard ones.

Comment: itself in psu is anything different ? gs and g ? 

which is better that buy ?

Comment: If you care about the noise level, buy GS. If not, buy cheaper G.